# Run AI Platform Notebook with Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, gcp-ai-platform-training

I have a python script `generate_trends.py` stored with the instance name `python-20201013-153823` as a notebook inside the AI Platform. What would be the best way to run that script directly from a cloud run using Flask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloud Run can serve stateless container that answers to HTTP request.

If you create a Flask server, with an entry point which trigger your script (call the processing function in your `generate_trends.py` file), package this in a container and deploy.

Take care of this:

- No GPU are attachable to a Cloud Run instance
- No dist can be attached to a Cloud Run instance. You have a in-memory writable directory `/tmp`, but it's not persistent and in memory. Use databases or cloud Storage to persist states
- Only 4 CPUs and up to 4 Gb of memory. You can't add more on an instance
- The request must be responded in less than 60 minutes
- You can't perform processing outside request handling (batch processing for example). CPU is throttled outside request processing period.